"unable to write to user settings" error message
WHY cannot I find a current useable answer to the error message "unable to write to user setting" from VS Code
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine"-"Chrome" {
      "editor.underline": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
"clang.detectExtensionConflicts": false,`your text`
"debug.onTaskErrors": "showErrors",
"prettier.bracketSameLine": true, 
"workbench.editorAssociations": {`your text`
    "*.exe": "default"}`your text`
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
"editor.fontSize": 6,
"cmake.additionalCompilerSearchDirs": [
    "C:/msys64/mingw32/bin",
    "C:/msys64/clang32/bin",`your text`
    "C:/msys64/clang64/bin",`your text`
    "C:/msys64/clangarm64/bin",
    "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin"
],
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
"terminal.integrated.mouseWheelZoom": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 2

}
I tried answers from google searches but none show the elements in the settings.json that match what was generated for me when I opened a new file(folder)? There are no waring messages or error messages causing the error message.

Is it because the JSON is malformed because of the first line? "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine"-"Chrome" {... It uses a dash (-) instead of a colon (:), and it has an unexpected curly brace at the end ({)

The JSON you provided was completely malformed, it probably just couldn't read it. It looks like you copy-pasted the AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine key both before the starting curly brace, and without adding a comma at the end. (Along with a missing comma after workbench.editorAssociations)
I've fixed the formatting below:
{
  "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "Chrome",
  "editor.underline": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
  "clang.detectExtensionConflicts": false,
  "debug.onTaskErrors": "showErrors",
  "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.exe": "default"
  },
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
  "editor.fontSize": 6,
  "cmake.additionalCompilerSearchDirs": [
    "C:/msys64/mingw32/bin",
    "C:/msys64/clang32/bin",
    "C:/msys64/clang64/bin",
    "C:/msys64/clangarm64/bin",
    "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin"
  ],
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
  "terminal.integrated.mouseWheelZoom": true,
  "window.zoomLevel": 2
}


Do note that "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine" expects a path to a browser executable. If chrome is added to your PATH, then just "chrome" is fine. (Since the file is called "chrome.exe", at least on Windows)
